# How to call MySQL SELECT found_rows() on Querydsl?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

So, Querydsl has `calcFoundRows()` for MySQL queries, but how does one call `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` after the actual query? Or what is the way to read this value in a Querydsl way?

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic Querydsl way to do it is

```
SearchResults<Tuple> results = query.listResults(col1, col2, ...)
results.getTotal() // for total row count
results.getResults() // for limit + offset based view
```

Comment: Thanks, Timo, for both the answer and the excellent work on Querydsl!

Comment: `results.getTotal()` does not execute `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`, see [issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1060). Waiting for solution.